# Difference between kāmahā and kāmakṛt

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama, vishnu-sahasranama

Vishnu Sahasranama mentions the names kāmahā and kāmakṛt

> 1. kāmahā - He who destroys all desires
> 2. kāmakṛt - He who fulfills all desires

How can Vishnu do both? Why does he stress on not having desires and having desires? Which desires are fulfilled by him and which are destroyed by him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Vishnu Sahasranamam has been commented upon by three eminent Acharyas

1. Sripad Adi Shankaracharya, propounder of the Advaita philosophy
2. Sri Parasara Bhattar, follower of the Sripad Ramanuja philosophy(Vishishtadvaita)
3. Sri Satyasanda Tirtha (Dvaita)(available in sanskrit no english translations available :(  )

[Also the Commentary of Sripad Madhvacharya with one hundred meanings for each naama is lost :( ].

Sripad Adi Shankaracharya in his [commentary](https://archive.org/details/Vishnu.Sahasranama.with.the.Bhasya.of.Sankaracharya/mode/2up) explains the names in the following way :

> 294. Kāmahā - The destroyer of desires **in those who are desirous of salvation.**
> 295. Kāmakṛt - The fulfiller of desires **of those of Sattvika nature**

Sri Parasar Bhattar in his [commentary](https://www.sadagopan.org/pdfuploads/Bhagavad%20Guna%20Darpanam.pdf) explains the names in the following way :

> 295. Kāmahā - The destroyer of **materialistic desires(desires of wordly pleasures)** of those who have realised the qualities of Bhagavan mentioned in the names before **and who desire to attain him.**
> 296. Kāmakṛt - (Sri Parasara Bhattar translates this in a different way as the ***creator* of desirable things fit to be enjoyed including the desire to attain salvation** and not as *he who fulfills all desires* )

I think the above beautiful commentaries hopefully answer most of your questions.